# Skydrive the operation has timed out

Tags: c#, console-application, onedrive

I am trying to connect to skydrive with this code, it is console C# application:

```
var client = new SkyDriveServiceClient();

client.LogOn("username", "password");
```

and I got this exception: *The operation has timed out*.

Anyone know what is solution for this problem?

Comment: Are you able to connect to the SkyDrive server outside of your application?

Comment: where does the timeout happen.. the code you posted doesn't give much in regards to lending any viable solution.. post the full method where you are using this

Comment: Application is breaking at line where I try to LogOn.

Comment: Are you using the SkyDrive.NET API Client?

Comment: Yes I am using SkyDrive .Net API Client. There is on codeplex this information: LogOn timeout workaround: Change the Uri in the source code by : https://docs.live.net/SkyDocsService.svc See http://skydriveapiclient.codeplex.com/discussions/281417. But I am not sure what is solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, download the latest version (Changset 68942) from **[this](http://skydriveapiclient.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets)** 
location. After download open the project (located in folder trunk/src/SkyDriveServiceClient.sln) in Visual Studio and change the variable **SkyDocsServiceUri** in the class **SkyDocsServiceClient** to the following:

```
public static readonly Uri SkyDocsServiceUri = new Uri("https://docs.live.net/SkyDocsService.svc");
```

After the change compile the project to build the assembly file. Then you need to reference the assembly from your project and try to execute your code again.

Comment: How can I get source code for SkyDocsServiceClient, is it in dll?

Comment: Theres a button on the right site to download the latest version of source code.

Comment: I know that I downloaded dll, but I am not sure did you mean that code from above just put in my class in C# and that's it?

Comment: No, you must download the source code of the SkyDrive.NET API Client and you need to modify and compile it.